# Empty option item for sap.m.Select control

Tags: sapui5

I'm looking for property with which I could add an empty option item to sap.m.Select control. I saw some approaches the corresponding data source for items-aggregation should contain that empty item. My problem I'm not able to change my data source. Do I have to insert that item after the data has been received from data source (and every time the model has been refreshed)?

Comment: Different idea: Delete button next to the select. If you click on it, selected key will be cleared. No need for an extra item.

Answer (score 1):

[You could use the Property forceSelection="false"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32725638/5550071)

If that's not enough.. Yes you have to Insert an Item after the Data have been loaded by your ServiceModel. [If you need to indicate that none of the selection options are selected, or you need to allow the user not to select an option, provide (None) (1) as an option and place it at the beginning of the list.](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/select/#option-list1)